# number of days extraction using regular expression. Additional words coming

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract number of days from some strings using regex. My strings are as follows:

- The school will end in 30 days after November. Here I want to extract "30 days".
- The school will end in 30 working days after November. Here I want to extract "30 working days".
- The school will end in thirty days after November. Here I want to extract "thirty days".
- The school will end in thirty ( 30 ) calandar days after November. Here I want to extract "thirty ( 30 ) calandar days".
- The school will end in thirty (30) working days after November. Here I want to extract "thirty (30) working days".
- The school will end in 30-days after November. Here I want to extract "30-days".

but the regex I have written extracts:

- in 30 days
- in 30 working days
- in thirty days
- thirty ( 30 ) calandar days
- thirty (30) working days
- 30-days

respectively.

The first, second and third strings are not being extracted correctly.

My regex is as follows:

```
\w*(?:-\w*)*\s*\(?\s*\d*\s*\)?\s*[\w*]*\s*(?:year|month|day)s*\b
```

Comment: I think you're essentially trying to do natural language processing with a regex, which is probably always going to leave you with nasty edge cases. You might have more success looking at something like https://www.nltk.org/ to do the parsing and then making sense of the output.

Comment: Try this pattern and it will only not catch 4th and 5th string ((\d+.*)|(\S+.))(?:year|month|day)s*\b

Comment: @TomDalton Can you please try and tell which model I should try

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex string which exiges enough information to be sure that we're talking about a date, and matches all your test string.
As noted in the comments there are probably better tools than regex for this task. It matches all the test strings but won't match `in one hundred days`

```
^.*(in|after).*(\d{1,3}|(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|twenty|thirty|forty|fourty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety)).*(day|week|month|year).*$
```